# Creating a graph representing square sum relations

Tags: math, clojure, lisp

I'm trying to solve the square sum problem, more specifically creating a function that can help with the relations.

"the function should, given a set A of integers, produce a relation that includes tuple [a b],
     iff a and b are in A and their sum is a square number"

To my aid, I got a help function `square?`, that tests whether a passed integer is a squared number.

```
(defn square?
[n]

(= n (sqr (isqrt n)))
)
```

I took a shot in dark with this, but honestly I'm lost.

```
(defn sqr-sum-rel
  [A]
    (reduce (fn [a b] (
        if (square? (a + b))
         [a b]

        )) A )
)
```

Testing the function should return something like this:

```
(test? "test" (sqr-sum-rel (set (range 1 11))) #{[5 4] [2 2] [8 8] [4 5] [7 9] [1 3] [3 6] [6 10] [2 7] [1 8] [8 1] [7 2] [10 6] [6 3] [3 1] [9 7]})
```

I'm really new to Clojure and even functional programming in general, so any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, you can first generate all possible pairs of numbers from the set using [for](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) and then [filter](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter) those pair. Assuming `square?` is properly implemented, we write a helper function that will be the first argument that we pass to `filter`:

```
(defn sum-is-square? [coll]
  (square? (apply + coll)))
```

It takes a collection of numbers as argument and test if their sum is `square?`. Then we can write the complete function like

```
(defn sqr-sum-rel [A]
  (set (filter sum-is-square?  (for [a A
                                     b A]
                                 [a b]))))
```

that takes as argument a set `A` and first produces all pairs that can be formed by elements from this set, and then only keep those pairs for which `sum-is-square?` evaluates to `true`.

We can test it by passing in a set of numbers:

```
(sqr-sum-rel (set (range 1 11)))
;; => #{[8 8] [2 2] [7 2] [5 4] [6 3] [1 3] [1 8] [8 1] [7 9] [2 7] [3 6] [10 6] [4 5] [9 7] [3 1] [6 10]}
```

**Added:** A briefer implementation as suggested by the original poster uses the `:when` option of `for`:

```
(defn sqr-sum-rel [A]
  (set (for [a A
             b A :when (square? (+ a b))]
          [a b]))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I drew some inspiration from it and wrote a version without an additional helper function: `(set (for [a A b A :when (square? (+ a b) )] [a b]))`. Would there be any downsides to using this one, eg is it bad from an idiomatic point of view or things in that manner?

Comment: In my opinion, it is as good, or even more readable. I was not aware of the `:when` feature, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i would also guess that the the number in set can't form the pair with itself, and also there is no need to compare pair members in reverse order, since we already know they form the relation needed. I would update it like this:

```
(defn sq-rel [a-set]
  (seq (for [[x & t] (take-while seq (iterate rest a-set))
             y t
             :when (square? (+ x y))]
         [x y])))
```

this one is more or less like an imperative

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
  for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) 
    if (isSquare(a[i] + a[j])) {
      res.push([a[i], a[j]])
    }
  }
}
```

in repl:

```
user> (sq-rel #{1 2 3 4 5 6})
;;=> ([1 3] [4 5] [6 3])
```